# Allow Zero Length on Connection String returns 'Cannot Find Installable ISAM'

Tags: delphi, ms-access, connection-string, isam

I keep getting

> Cannot Find installable ISAM

While trying to connect to my database on DELPHI.

I Use access 97 for my database.

This is the connection string i'm using

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='C:\Program Files\Koinonia Software\Habil Empresarial\Dados\habil.mdb';Persist Security Info=False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=amoragape ;Jet OLEDB:Allow Zero Length = True;
```

It started after i've inserted the

```
Jet OLEDB:Allow Zero Length = True;
```

parameter.

Can somebody help?

Comment: Remove the extra space between `amoragape` and it's semicolon terminator (IOW, change `amoragape ;Jet OLEDB` to `amoragape;Jet`).

Comment: The MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicates that `Jet OLEDB:Allow Zero Length` is an OLEDB *Column property*, not an OLEDB *Initialization property*. What benefit do you expect to receive when you add that property to the connection string?